# Negative margin, z-index and click blocking

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm using negative margins to layout two columns:

```
<div id="left-column"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
<div id="right-column">
    <div id="right-column-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#left-column { width: 200px; float: left;}
#right-column { margin-left: -200px; width: 100%; float: left;}
#right-column-inner { margin-left: 200px; float: left;}
```

Unfortunately, in Opera 10.54, Safari 4 and FF 3+, the checkbox isn't clickable as the `#right-column` is capturing the click before it propogates down to the checkbox.

I've tried manipulating the z-index but no luck.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you change a positioning property in CSS (such as `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` or `z-index`) you have to specify a `position` property other than `static` (the default).

So change the `z-index` *and the `position`* CSS properties.

```
#left-column { width: 200px; float: left; position:relative; z-index:100;}
```

Comment: The right answer and a better understanding of a corner of css!  Never would have associated z-index with position.